# C++ class declaration error in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

I am porting a C++ project to Mac using Xcode. Now I have a class that is declared as following:

```
namespace poi {
class AesCipher : public SymetricCipher {
public:
    AesCipher();
    virtual ~AesCipher ();

    //more method declarations here...
};
}
```

Yet Xcode will present me an error for the line of the public: statement:

```
 C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

I assume this has to do with the namespace but I'm not that experienced with C++.
I have no idea what this error is trying to say to me. Maybe someone has seen such an error before and could just point me in the right direction what kind of mistake I might have made.

Comment: It will tell you where that error is exactly.  That would help us too...

Comment: Could you produce a short, complete program that demonstrates the error? See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: Most probably, you have some declaration of a member function, which does not have a return type.

Comment: Where is SymetricCipher defined, is it in namespace poi, and are you including the necessary library in XCode if its from a lib or dynlib?

Comment: @trojanfoe h said the error is in the `public:` statement.

Comment: Have you included the header where `SymetricCipher` is declared?

Comment: `SymetricCipher` is declared in the same name space and is one of my own classes (Xcode does not report any errors there). I am working on a sscce but I could not reproduce the error there, yet. Also interesting is that the error vanishes if I just remove the `public:` statement